# Account creation program is not reading file properly

Tags: python

I've been making a program that allows the user to create an account which saves to a txt file, and allows them to login. The text now saves to the file (which I was unable to make work earlier due to using `w+` instead of `a+`) but I am not quite sure I understand how `split()` works. When I try to use the info saved to the txt file the program returns that the username cannot be found. If anyone could fix this code id appreciate it.
I began a few weeks ago so a lot of this is new to me.

```py
        AccountsFile = open("AccountProj.txt", "a+")
        AccountList = [line.split('\n') for line in AccountsFile.readlines()]
        
        #Creates an account 
        def createaccount():
            while True:
                
        newname = (input("Please create a username: "))
                
        if newname in AccountsFile:
            print("Username already in use.")
            continue
                
        elif newname not in AccountsFile:

            newpassword = input("Please create a password: ")

            checkpassword = input("Re-enter password: ")
                
            if checkpassword == newpassword:
                print("Account Sucessesfuly created!")
                AccountsFile.write(newname + '\n')
                AccountsFile.write(checkpassword + '\n')
                AccountsFile.close()
                break

            elif checkpassword != newpassword:
                print("Passwords do not match")
                continue
        #Logs into an account

        def loginaccount():
            while True:
                
        username_entry = input("Enter username: ")
                
        if username_entry not in AccountList:
            print("Username not found. Please enter a valid name")
            continue
        if username_entry in AccountList:
            password_entry = input("Enter password: ")
                    
            if password_entry in AccountList[AccountList.index(username_entry) + 1]:
                print("Login sucessful!")
                AccountsFile.close()
                break
            if password_entry not in AccountList[AccountList.index(username_entry) + 1]:
                print("Username and password do not match. Please try again.")
                AccountsFile.close()
                continue
while True:
        
                    
        #Asks if user wants to create or login to an account            
        loginchoice = input("Would you like to login? (Y/N) ")
        
        if loginchoice in ('Y', 'N'):
        
            if loginchoice == 'Y':
                loginaccount()

            if loginchoice == 'N':
                
                createchoice = str(input("Would you like to create an account? (Y/N) "))
                
                if createchoice in ('Y', 'N'):
                
                    if createchoice == 'Y':
                        createaccount()

                    if createchoice == 'N':
                        pass
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check AccountList - both [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and `readlines()` create a list for you, so you have a list of lists and your username_entry check can't work that way.

Comment: I am not quite sure i get your instruction. Also, i noticed that when i print the contents of the file, i get nothing despite multiple strings being in the file.

Comment: AccountList is a list of lists, therefore "username_entry in AccountList" will be always false. Either you make a normal list where a username is one element, or you have to chance your 'username_entry in AccountList' check

Comment: Ok--I rewrote the second two lines as: AccountsFileRead = AccountsFile.read() and
AccountList = AccountsFileRead.split(' ') . I ran this in a seperate window to make sure it worked, but i got a blank list when printing it. But then i changed the labels and it worked(??). Why would this be happening? EDIT: it was because mode was 'a+' and not 'r'. there goes 2 hours of my day.

Comment: @qmayo14 to get all the lines in a list within list use .readlines()

Comment: This means List = File.readlines(), List[0] = First line in text file and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
def CreateAccount():
    Username = input("Username: ") #Enter Username
    Username.replace(" ", "") #Removes spaces (Optional)
    AppValid = True #Default value that changes if duplicate account found
    File = open("Accounts.txt","r") #Checking if username already exits
    for Line in File:
        Account = Line.split(",")
        if Account[0] == Application:
            print("There is already an Account with this Username")
            AppValid = False #Changing value if username exits
    File.close()
    if AppValid == True: #If username not found, carries on
        Password = input("Password: ") #Asks for Password
        CheckPassword = input("Password: ")
        if Password == CheckPassword:
            print("Password's Match!") #Password Match
        else:
            print("No match")
        File = open("Accounts.txt","a") #Writing new account to File
        File.write(Username + "," + Password + "\n")
        File.close()
def ViewAccount(Username, Password):
    File = open("Accounts.txt","r")
    Data = File.readlines()
    File.close()
    if len(Data) == 0:
        print("You have no Accounts") #Account not found since no accounts
    else:
        AccountFound = false
        for X in Data: #Looping through account data
            if X[0] == Username: #Username match
                if X[1] == Password:
                    AccountFound = true
                    print("Account Found")
        if AccountFound = false:
            print("Account not FOUND")
```

Theres some code i threw together (JK my hand hurts from typing that and my keyboard is screaming) but back to the point .split(" ") would split a string into a list based on spaces for that example, eg:

```
String = "Hello There"
String = String.split(" ") #Or String.split() only owrks for spaces by default
print("Output:", String[0]) #Output: Hello
print("Output:", String[1]) #Output: There

String = "Word1, Word2"
String = String.split(", ") #Splits string by inserted value
print("Output:", String[0]) #Output: Word1
print("Output:", String[1]) #Output: Word2

String = "abcdefghijklmnop"
String = String.split("jk") #Splits string by inserted value
print("Output:", String[0]) #Output: abcdefghi
print("Output:", String[1]) #Output: lmnop
```

Comment: Ok -- i believe i have the actual code fixed now, but for some reason it is not recognizing that there are words within the txt file.